# Have electron auto-reload for the changes in the main or renderer source?

Tags: webpack, electron

I would like to have a dev environment for `electron`, when it would auto reload itself (hot-reload perhaps?) when there are changes in the source of the `main` or `renderer`. The big fat obstacle in my case is that both sources (main and renderer) have to be transpiled and minified for the production.

What are the options?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `electron-reload`, You can get more information from  [here](https://github.com/yan-foto/electron-reload)

Add following lines into your entry js

```
require('electron-reload')(__dirname);
```